# What proof do we have that space is expanding?

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion, big-bang

how can we really say that space is expanding when we cannot see the distant galaxies forming nor are the planets nearby newly formed, nor is anything expanding in size nor are we going far away? (sorry if it's unclear)

Comment: Have you read the answers to [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59386/)? The gist is that we see the vast majority of distant galaxies moving directly away from us implying that either the Earth is at the centre of the universe or space is expanding uniformly. What additional questions to you have?

Comment: Technically, we don't. We do have a lot of astronomical evidence, though.

Comment: @or1426  sorry for asking a duplicate question :(

Answer (score 0):

Red shift. is a really quick answer. whichever way we look, stuff is moving away from us. and the further away it is the faster it's moving.