# The growing expansion speed of our universe

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion, big-bang

Is there a definitive way to calculate the speed at which the expansion of our universe is growing?
To clarify i don't want to know the speed. I want to know if there is a way to calculate the increase in speed of expansion over time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [At what speed does our universe expand?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13388/)

Comment: Please make the effort to [search the site for duplicates](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=speed+universe+is%3Aquestion) before you post a question.

Comment: Yes. One can measure the rate of expansion by looking at the redshift of distant objects.

The thread mentioned by @JohnRennie has some very nice answers.

Comment: Yes, the speed of acceleration can be calculated by comparing the visible brightness of distant supernovas to their redshift. However the hypothesis of acceleration is contested, because not all observations support it.

Comment: The question is unclear.  Do you want to theoretically *calculate* the rate of expansion of a typical distance, or to experimentally *measure* it ?

Comment: See section 3.6.2 of [The Hubble Constant - Caltech Astronomy](http://www.astro.caltech.edu/~george/ay127/readings/FreedmanMadore2010.pdf)

Comment: Or read [Dark Energy and the Accelerating Universe - Caltech Astronomy](http://www.astro.caltech.edu/~george/ay21/readings/Friemanetal_DE_ARAA.pdf)